# How to create a list with rational elements

Tags: haskell

i try the following. The function **cant** :: Int -> Rational should give the n-th element of the list of the type Rational.

Especially, the list begins with the element 1/1 and has the following properties:
(lets say a/b is the fraction, and to construct rationals i use the operator % from the module Data.Ratio. So for a/b, is write a%b. And gcd is the function which gives me greatest common divisor)

```
if(a-b)==0                       then a % (a+b)
if (a-b)<0 && a+1/= b+1          then (a+1) % (b-1)
if (a-b)>0 && (gcd a b = a || b) then (a-b) % (a+b)
```

so, for example, as i said: when i start with a / b = 1 / 1 .Because of 1-1 = 0 , then the second element of the list would be 1 /2. 
Then i would take the second element 1 / 2. Because 1-2= -1 < 0 **and** 1+1 /= 2+1, then the 3rd element of the list would be 2/1.
And then i would take 2/1, and so on...

So, my idea was to construct a list beginning with 1%1 , so something like

```
[(1%1)..]
```

and take the first element which is indeed (1%1) and create with it the second elemnt using the conditions above, but [(1%1)..]  does not work.
(how i come to [(1%1)..]  : on some sites i see the notation [1 ..] for [1,2,3,4, and so on], and i taught with [(1%1)..]  it would be the same)

and i have no other idea found yet. Can someone offer me another strategy? Please not the code, because i want to learn it, so only your idea(s) would be perfect...xD

edit:
hello, thank you for your answers. The Collatz example helped me a lot. But for the solution i use the other idea. And now, I write the following:

```
import Data.Ratio

list :: [Rational]
list = initial : map calculateNext list


calculateNext :: Rational -> Rational
calculateNext (a%b)                   | (a-b) == 0                     = a % (a+b)
                  | (a-b)<0 && (a+1) /= (b-1)      = (a+1)%(b-1)
                  | (a-b)>0 && (gcd a b == a || b) = (a-b)%(a+b)


initial :: Rational
initial = (1%1)
```

But the compiler says:

```
calculate.hs: 8:1:Parse error in pattern: calculateNext
```

I think it can not understand, what i try to express with the argument a%b...? Am I right?
If yes, how could it be solved such that it understand it ?

Comment: On the `[1..]` notation: it only works for types which are instances of the [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) type class, which is not the case for `Rational` (which is just a synonym for [`Ratio Integer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#t:Ratio)). Even if there was a predefined instance, it would only work for you if the `succ` function actually gave the next value in your Cantor enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

You might like [this blog post](http://mathlesstraveled.com/2008/01/07/recounting-the-rationals-part-ii-fractions-grow-on-trees/), and you can view an implementation of the ideas given there in the [`positiveRationals` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-instances-base-1.0/docs/src/Data-Universe-Instances-Base.html#line-51) provided by the [universe package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe). (The definition of the `(+++)` helper function is given [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0/docs/src/Data-Universe-Helpers.html).)

To do *exactly* what you ask, I suggest looking into the `iterate` function. Write the algorithm you proposed as a function which takes a single step, then pass that function to `iterate` and it will run all the steps for you. Here is an example of a similar algorithm to give you an idea of what I mean. Instead of the rationals, we'll do the Collatz sequence -- it's similar, but different enough that it contains no spoilers.

The Collatz sequence goes like this: to get the next step, if the number is even, divide by two; otherwise, triple it and add one. In code,

```
collatzStep n
    | even n    = n `div` 2
    | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

collatz n = iterate collatzStep n
```

You can see the Collatz sequence starting from, say, 30, by running this in ghci:

```
*Main> take 10 (collatz 30)
[30,15,46,23,70,35,106,53,160,80]
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with a simple recursion pattern:

```
list = initial : map calculateNext list
```

In this case, `initial == 1 % 1`, and `calculateNext` would be the code you have outlined above with the `if` statements.

Comment: I tried to build up the calculateNext function, but obviously there is a problem. I presented my solution under my question above.