# Building a list from left-to-right in Haskell without ++

Tags: list, haskell, cons

Is there a way to build lists from left-to-right in Haskell without using `++`?

`cons` is a constant time operation and I want to keep the code efficient. I feel like there's a general way to take advantage of Haskell's laziness to do something like this, but I can't think of it.

Right now I'm writing a function that creates a Collatz Sequence, but it's building the list in the wrong direction:

```
module CollatzSequence where

collatz :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> [a];
collatz n l
  | n <= 0    = error "Enter a starting number > 0"
collatz n []  = collatz n [n]
collatz n l@(x:_)
  | x == 1    = l
  | even x    = collatz n ((div x 2):l)
  | otherwise = collatz n ((x*3 + 1):l)
```

In GHCi:

```
*CollatzSequence> collatz 13 []
[1,2,4,8,16,5,10,20,40,13]
```

Comment: What a coincidence, I've just implemented the Collatz sequence as an [example for an unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23767928/791604). Perhaps it's enough of a nudge for you to get the trick! (In short, drop your accumulator... just start returning things.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is indeed a way to take advantage of laziness. In Haskell you can safely do recursive calls *inside* lazy data constructors, and there will be no risk of stack overflow or divergence. Placing the recursive call inside a constructor eliminates the need for an accumulator, and the order of elements in the list will also correspond to the order in which they are computed:

```
collatz :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatz n | n <= 1 = []
collatz n = n : collatz next where
    next = if even n then div n 2 else n * 3 + 1
```

For example, the expression `head $ collatz 10` evaluates to `head (10 : <thunk>)` which evaluates to `10`, and the thunk in the tail will stay unevaluated. Another advantage is that list nodes can be garbage collected while iterating over the list. `foldl' (+) 0 (collatz n)` runs in constant space, since the visited nodes are no longer referenced by the rest of the program and can be freed. This is not the case in your original function, since - being tail recursive - it cannot provide any partial result until the whole list is computed.

Comment: That first paragraph is as clear as a bell. I'll be using that explanation next time I talk about tail recursion in Haskell. Nice answer.

Comment: Maybe change `collatz n | n <= 1 = []` to `collatz n | n == 1 = [1]` to terminate on 1 and not the element just before 1?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
collatz :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
collatz n
  | n <= 0    = error "Enter a starting number > 0"
  | n == 1    = [1]
  | even n    = n : collatz (div n 2)
  | otherwise = n : collatz (n*3 + 1)
```